# End asp.net application in application_begin after detecting wrong db in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this old asp.net application and for some reasons that i will not get into here, it has been running in production on the wrong database.

We do not have any provision for a build server at this point and i'm just looking for a quick way to prevent the application from loading when my code in global.asax detects that the db is not the production db.

I use something like this:

```
 foreach (ConnectionStringSettings s in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    if (s.ConnectionString.Contains(ProdDataBaseServer) == ValidateCondition)

        return false;
    }
```

My question is are there better ways to do this and which event in global asax would best fit to handle this check?

Thanks in advance

B

Comment: What would you like to have happening if the site IS connected to the wrong database? Inform the user? Crash violently? Work as usual, but not perform any database operations?

Comment: Lock the site down. This should of course never happen but if it does happen, we just want to lock the site down with a standard message that users can report to us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call me superstitious (by all means do) but I wouldn't want to rely entirely on Session_start or Application_start if it can be avoided. I still don't trust it to happen every time a user appears on site (because there were known issues with that about 15 years ago or so).

If you are using some form of Base-object which your Pages inherit from, you could perform the check in some early event such as OnInit of the Base-Page class.
Or if you perform some type of user validation on each page call, you could do the database check along with the user check.
I would probably redirect the users to a (html) page that says "site is down", and kill off their session and all that.

Or, if this propblem doesn't occur while running, but always because a developer forgets to change the code before doing a release, you could solve it already at compile time. You could do the check right after you build; Run a post build script that checks if your web.config contains a certain string which will be unique to the right (or wrong) database.

```
if (theFileAsString.Contains("Data Source=THE_WRONG_ONE")){
    // Perform actions to inform user that this compilation should not be released
}
```